# Arcobjects - Properties Grid

Tags: arcobjects, vba, grids-graticules

Does anybody know a way, in VBA, to change the grid interval?

For example: if my layout´s scale is 1:2000, my grid will have 200 meters interval and my layout´s scale is 1:5000, my grid will have 500 meters interval.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: it can be done with python?